# reCAPTCHA change language based on current locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I'm using `gem "recaptcha"`

Currently on it only shows up in English:

http://cl.ly/image/11073e0p1J0A

My form:

```
  %li.captcha
    = recaptcha_tags
```

Is there a way to show the reCAPTCHA in English if current locale is English and in French if current locale is French?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer this but i was looking for this answer today.

So this worked for me:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en'></script>
```

On hl you put language codes.

Found the answer on the docs, on the Configuration section:
[here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

I hope you can use it on rails too!